# Search HTML with Regex

Tags: html, regex

I read somewhere that regex is pretty bad at HTML. I think this case could be different.

search among html for such patterns

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/abc.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum 1" title="Lorem Ipsum 1" class="image-medium caption" /><figcaption>Lorem Ipsum 1</figcaption>

<img src="http://example.com/images/abc.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum 2" title="Lorem Ipsum 2" class="image-large caption" /><figcaption>Lorem Ipsum 1</figcaption>
```

replace with

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/abc.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum 1" title="Lorem Ipsum 1" class="image-medium caption" /><figcaption>Lorem Ipsum 1</figcaption>

<img src="http://example.com/images/abc.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum 2" title="Lorem Ipsum 2" class="image-large caption" /><figcaption>Lorem Ipsum 2</figcaption>
```

Note: small difference in the class, large and medium

In other words: I need to extract the title and then append with title within the figcaption tag.

How should I go about this with Regex?

Comment: make use of jquery... you can do all these very easily

Comment: Maybe I'm getting old, but I don't see any difference between your two examples. The classes are the same.

Comment: I'm missing the difference, the classes are the same, no? In any case, *when*/where do you want to updatebthe HTML?

Comment: He wants to take the title text and put it into the figcaption. It's a bad example, though, since his title/figcaption texts are so much alike.

Comment: The class is different: image-large and image-medium. I am using editor with reg. Now, I am at <IMG\b[^>]*>(.*?)  Able to find the tag. I need to search within and then append. Caption are different.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions here won't be such a great idea - it doesn't require much change in the HTML in order for this *not* to work.

```
$text = preg_replace('/title="(.*)"(.*)<figcaption>(.*)<\/figcaption>/U',
                     'title="$1"$2<figcaption>$1</figcaption>',$text);
```

The above will work with the example in the question. Just to make it a little more clear what it does, it will also work with this.

```
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="Foo image" title="A great time with foo!" class="something" /><figcaption>Get this out</figcaption>
<img src="bar.jpg" alt="Bar image" title="Here is bar!" class="nothing" /><figcaption>This be gone</figcaption>
```

with

```
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="Foo image" title="A great time with foo!" class="something" /><figcaption>A great time with foo!</figcaption>
<img src="bar.jpg" alt="Bar image" title="Here is bar!" class="nothing" /><figcaption>Here is bar!</figcaption>
```

Comment: How do I use your expression? Can you put in a form that can be used in editor? :)

Comment: something I can put in my "Find" and "Replace" field of my Regex-supported-code editor (Expresso or Xcode)